# What were the 2 satellites I saw this morning?

Tags: amateur-observing, artificial-satellite, satellite

This morning at 6:03am Israel time (3:03 UTC) I saw, simultaneously, what appeared to be 2 satellites streaking across the sky directly overhead. If I remember correctly, they were both coming from NW (but it was early).

Does anybody know what they were, or how I can find out?

I live in Mitzpe Netofa, lon/lat about 35.39/32.80.

Comment: Almost certainly not astronomical objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about astronomy

Comment: @Walter Visual observation of objects above 100 km sounds like amateur astronomy to me. The amateur is not qualified to determine whether satellites are natural or artificial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to figure it out would be to use the site "In the Sky" (https://in-the-sky.org/). You can enter time, date and location to identify satellites. This would at least be able to tell you if what you saw was a satellite.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it was COSMO-SKYMED 1 and IRIS. I've seen satellites before but this was the first time I saw 2 simultaneously.